# An image cannot cover the full screen of a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I want to let an image to cover the whole screen of a mobile phone. When I preview on iPhone on a laptop, the image does not cover the full screen and it only covers a small part of the screen of the iPhone. The following is my code.

```
<style>
    #panorama {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60vw;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="panorama"></div>
<script>
    var image = "images/ttu-wbb.jpg";
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        image = "images/ttu-wbb-m.jpg";
        var mobileDim = document.querySelector("#panorama");
        mobileDim.style.height = "100%";
        mobileDim.style.width = "100%";
    }

    pannellum.viewer('panorama', {
        "type": "equirectangular",
        "panorama": image,
        "autoRotate": -5,
        "autoLoad": true
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#panorama{
    background-size: cover ;
}
```